# Xamarin Android MediaPlayer not working - Resource.raw not found

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I am currently coding an android application in Xamarin C#. I want to play a Sound, and for that I am using the `MediaPlayer`.

```
MediaPlayer _player = MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resource.Raw.file)
```

The compiler gives me an error because,

> Resource does not contain a definition for 'Raw'

In my projects I can use `Resource.String`, `Resource.Mipmap`; I can use everything except the thing I need. I tried also uppercase and lowercase in the `Resources/Raw` directory, but it did not work. What is my error?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This error might pop up after installing an update. I got this error after installing update 15.7.4 in VS2017. The partial class Raw in Resource.Designer.cs wasn't being generated and so wasn't being recognized inside my Activities. Restarting the project, deleting the bin and obj files and rebuilding the project didn't work.

However, after restarting my computer it magically worked.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have raw folder under Resource folder?
If you already have, check your file name in raw folder. File name could not contain symbols, such as period, dash and space.
Finally, checking Resource.Designer.cs, there should have public partial class Raw.

```
public partial class Raw
    {

        // aapt resource value: 0x7f040000
        public const int Moves_Like_Jagger = 2130968576;

        static Raw()
        {
            global::Android.Runtime.ResourceIdManager.UpdateIdValues();
        }

        private Raw()
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Were you by chance trying to use the Xamarin Player to deploy your app? If so, try running via traditional USB debugging or emulator. There may be some kind of bug in Xamarin Player that breaks resources.